# How to get the full output of a query even when the constraint parameter shows the same result

Tags: postgresql

i have the following query:

```
select  names as "names"  from tbl1 where id_name  in
                    (select owner_id from tbl2 where id in
                    (select  product_id FROM tbl3 where tbl3.id IN (10, 11, 15)))
```

and I get as response because `id` 10 and 11 results in same name `Ford`

```
names
Ford
Fiat
```

What I want to do:

1. to get the two lines as response, even if they are the same:

   ```
     names
     Ford
     Ford
     Fiat
   ```
2. I want to get the tbl3.id in the result, like this:

   ```
   id    names
   10    Ford
   11    Ford
   15    Fiat
   ```

Comment: What you are describing is the result of a "join" between two or three tables, rather than the nested conditions you have written. I think you would benefit from finding a general SQL tutorial in a format that suits you (text, video, interactive, etc), which would probably cover this fairly early on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @IMSoP you need to JOIN your tables. Try something like this :

```
SELECT t3.id, t1.names
  FROM tbl1 AS t1
 INNER JOIN tbl2 AS t2
    ON t1.id_name = t2.owner_id
 INNER JOINO tbl3 AS t3
    ON t2.id = t3.product_id
 WHERE t3.id IN (10, 11, 15)
```